# How to extract basePath with pathParameters with RestAssured

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured

So I am using RestAssured to test some endpoints and pulling the test result into an Allure report.

I am currently trying to fill the report with useful information about each test case, like the endopoint pinged.
To extract the url I tried using the following:

```
    RequestSpecification requestSpec = RestAssured.given().spec(Request.getRequestSpecification());
    QueryableRequestSpecification queryRequest = SpecificationQuerier.query(requestSpec);
    String retrieveURI = queryRequest.getBaseUri();
    System.out.println("Base URI is : "+retrieveURI);
    String retrievePath = queryRequest.getBasePath();
    System.out.println("Base PATH is : "+retrievePath);
```

where the `Request.getRequestSpecification()` returns a `RequestSpecification` build with `RequestSpecBuilder` .

the thing is my basePath is something like `/info/{unitId}/something` the value here is filled with a pathParameter once built. but the block
`String retrievePath = queryRequest.getBasePath();`
`System.out.println("Base PATH is : "+retrievePath);`

returns my basepath with {unitId} in it instead of the actual path parameter passed.

Is there a way to extract the basePath of a RestAssured request with the pathParameter within it ?

note, I know there is .log().uri() but this outputs the info in the counsole and I need it in a variable to send it to the Allure report.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone this might help, `QueryableRequestSpecification` actually has a `.getURI()` method that wil essentially return the full uri with the pathParameters in it :

```
RequestSpecification requestSpec = RestAssured.given().spec(Request.getRequestSpecification());
QueryableRequestSpecification queryRequest = SpecificationQuerier.query(requestSpec);
String retrieveURI = queryRequest.getURI()
System.out.println("Full URI is : "+retrieveURI);
```

I use intelliJ on windows and for some reason the method was showing up red in my IDE

point of reference https://javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.1/io/restassured/specification/QueryableRequestSpecification.html#getURI--